# Nestjs Override property in child class dto nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, enums, nestjs

I have staus enum like this

```
export enum Status {
  Active = "Active",
  Inactive = "Inactive",
}
```

and i have UserStatus like this

```
export enum UserStatus {
  Active = Status.Active,
};
```

and i have one common dto that holds the status

```
export class CommonDto {

  @ApiProperty({ description: "Status", required: true })
  status: Status;
```

and in my user dto i am extending this class liek this

```
export class UserDto extends CommonDto {

  @ApiProperty({ description: "Status", required: true, enum: UserStatus })
  status: UserStatus;
```

but this is showing error

```
Property 'status' in type 'UserDto' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CommonDto'.
  Type 'UserStatus' is not assignable to type 'Status'
```

any help?

Comment: with extends you can `override` methods and so on, but you can't change the type! What you do is changing `Status` to `UserStatus`.
Better use `default` value in `@ApiProperty`

Comment: in my system there are 15 entities so i created common dto , 2 entity has the differnt status than Status , like in this UserStatus is subset of Status.. can u give an example how can i sort this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to solve it.

### First way; generic classes

In this case we set the type of the `status` generic. So you can give each class that extends from CommonDto a own type for status.

```
export class CommonDto<T> {
  @ApiProperty({ description: "Status", required: true })
  status: T;
  // ...
}

export class UserDto extends CommonDto<UserStatus> {
  // ...
}
```

### Second way: union types

You can set multiple, possible types in typescript like this:

```
export type AnyStatus = Status | UserStatus;

export class CommonDto {
  @ApiProperty({ description: "Status", required: true })
  status: AnyStatus;
  // ...
}

export class UserDto extends CommonDto {
  @ApiProperty({ description: "Status", required: true, enum: UserStatus })
  status: AnyStatus;
  // ...
}
```

### Third way: Use intersected types

In typescript you can "delete" properties and "add" properties in extended classes to maniupulate it types, like this:

```
type WithUserStatus<T> = Omit<T, 'status'> & { status: UserStatus };

type UserDto = WithUserStatus<CommonDto>;
```

[Read](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) more about intesection

*These are the options you have to go. In your case I would set status in each class (except the base class (CommonDto)) separately with its own type.*